# golang switch got an ` used as value` error?

Tags: go

I don't know really why `switch t := some.(type){}` works well, but if I tried  `switch k := f.Kind(){}` or so on.

```
.\mym.go:58: k := f.Kind() used as value

exit status 2
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are right, it is syntax error; it should be SimpleStmt or
ExprSwitchStmt = "switch" [ SimpleStmt ";" ] [ Expression ] "{" { ExprCaseClause } "}" .
see:
https://golang.org/ref/spec#Switch_statements
 In an expression switch, the cases contain expressions that are compared against the value of the switch expression. 
And this will work:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Test struct {
    kind int
}

func (s *Test) Kind() int {
    return s.kind
}
func main() {
    f := &Test{12}
    //fmt.Println(k := f.Kind()) //syntax error: unexpected :=, expecting comma or )
    switch k := f.Kind(); k {
    case 12:
        fmt.Println(k) //12
    case 0:
        fmt.Println("Bye!")
    }
}
```